# script to install MSI silently

Tags: windows, batch-file, installation, silent-installer

Hi am using the following to silent install msi file name : agent.msi

```
C:\Users\Administrator > msiexec /qb /Lv* install.log /i agent.msi SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\Temp\Agent.ssl
```

After running the above command when am checking install.log file giving error as `Installation Error: 1602  / 1603`

I have cleared temp files and running folder is non encrypted, and having full admin access.

May i know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

MSI errors are often hard to find, since the install log will record a lot of information as part of the rollback that occurs after the error. Typically you should search for the string `return value 3` as this will typically highlight the action where the real error occurred. Once you have that information there will be more to go on.

Comment: Hi stephen, i have checked saying that return value 3 : displaying that 
Erroe 1309: C:\Temp\program files\symantec\critical system protection\agent\IDS\bin\SISIDSSERVICE.exe. Verify that the files exists and you can access it

Comment: Looks like an issue with the MSI package to me. You should contact Symantec tech support and send them your install log. You should give them more information about how you have extracted the MSI as it's not clear why the installer should be looking in that folder.